# iOS swift: App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource

Tags: ios, swift, api, https

Evening, I'm working on an app based on the SWAPI (Star Wars api: https://swapi.co/documentation)

And I got the **ATS Error**: `App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.`

I can't understand the reason. My `baseURL` is on **https format**

```
struct NetworkManager {
    let baseURL = "https://swapi.co/api/"
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

    func fetchEndpoint(endpoint: Endpoint, completion: @escaping (_ response: Result) -> Void) {
        self.fetchURL(url: baseURL + endpoint.URL(), completion: completion)
    }

    func fetchURL(url: String, completion: @escaping (_ response: Result) -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: url)!

        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                completion(.Failure(error))
            } else {
                if let data = data {
                    if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) {

                        OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                            switch json {
                            case let objectResponse as JSONArray: completion(.Success(objectResponse as AnyObject?))
                            case let objectResponse as JSONDict: completion(.Success(objectResponse as AnyObject?))
                            default: break
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Please give me and hint!!
I'm just a newbie, and I'm guessing that the SWAPI supports only the http protocol.

Comment: I was surprised to see that happen too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to be that you are right, that SWAPI supports only the http protocol.

To support also an unsecure connection do this:

1. Open the `info.plist` file
2. Add the Key called `App Transport Security Settings` as `Dictionary` (Dictionary should be the default type)
3. Add the Subkey called `Allow Arbitrary Loads` as `Boolean` (Boolean should be the default type). Set it to `YES`

See also the Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: are you 100% sure? because reading the doc of SWAPI there are some examples with https

Comment: ok sry, did not looked that close enough. Your are right. Then its strange

Comment: but there are only two examples with https and the rest with http. maybe a typo

Comment: He can just add a domain in exception rather than disabling the whole ATS feature